# Not able to get next td value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value inside td. What exactly I am doing is below:

HTML code rendered:

```
<td>
 <span style="padding-left: 15px;" onclick="GetAccountNodes(2,17,this);">-</span> 
 <span onclick="GetNodeDetails(2,17,this);"> Capital Accounts</span>
</td>
<td style="display:block">3.17.</td>
```

My Script is as follows:

```
 function GetNodeDetails(levelId, parentGroupID, ele) {

        var x = $(this).parent().next('td').html();
        alert(x);

    }
```

But it is throwing "undefined" error. 
What am I doing wrong here ?

I also tried using like below"

```
$(this).parent('td').next('td').html();
```

But to no avail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script should probably be:

```
function GetNodeDetails(levelId, parentGroupID, ele) {
    var x = $(ele).parent().next('td').html();
    alert(x);
}
```

You're passing in `this` to the function as the `ele` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. How could I miss it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function GetNodeDetails(levelId, parentGroupID, ele) {
  //debugger;
    var x = $(ele).parent().next('td').html();
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
<td>
 <span style="padding-left: 15px;" onclick="GetAccountNodes(2,17,this);">-</span> 
 <span onclick="GetNodeDetails(2,17,this);"> Capital Accounts</span>
</td>
<td style="display:block">3.17.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Note:** Question does not contains Td tag inside Table and Tr tag. So just a note here browser may remove tr tag or `$(this).parent()` may not return tr element and eventually your function would fail to get the value of td element you want to show in alert.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working example in fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/t3cjge55/10/

```
<script>
    function GetNodeDetails(levelId, parentGroupID, ele) {
      //debugger;
    //var x = $(ele).parent().next('td').html();
       alert($(ele).parent().next('td').html());
    }

</script>
<table>
    <tr>
<td>
 <span style="padding-left: 15px;" onclick="GetAccountNodes(2,17,this);">-</span> 
 <span class="getNodeDetails" onclick="GetNodeDetails(2,17,this);"> Capital Accounts</span>
</td>
<td style="display:block">3.17.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```